# How to use Shiro without login page for WEB application

Tags: java, struts2, shiro

I have a WEB Application which wrote with Struts2. And It doesn't have a login page. The login page is a div of the main page.
I want to use Shiro for security of my application.

I don't understand how to use Shiro without the login page.
And I don't understand how to pass a username to Shiro from Struts Action.

Please help me.
Thank you.

My Action:

```
public class InternalLoginAction extends ActionSupport {

private String remoteUser;

public String execute() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    remoteUser = request.getRemoteUser();
    if (remoteUser != null) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(user.calcIdTemp(remoteUser));
        user.setName(remoteUser);
        user.setCompanyId(LoginDao.getUserCompanyId(remoteUser.toUpperCase()));
        user.setExternal(false);
        user.saveSession();

        //I want to pass username to Shiro here.

    }
    return SUCCESS;
}

public String getRemoteUser() {
    return remoteUser;
}

public void setRemoteUser(String remoteUser) {
    this.remoteUser = remoteUser;
}
```

}

I am sorry, but I cannot show all page. Only this is:

```
<div id="login-dialog" title="Authorization" class="hide">
  <form id="login-dialog-form" >
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Login:</td>
      <td>
        <input id="login-dialog-login" name="form.login" size="22" maxlength="22" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-parsley-required="true" autofocus>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password:</td>
      <td>
       <input id="login-dialog-pass" name="form.pw" type="password" size="22" maxlength="22" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-minlength="6" data-parsley-maxlength="20">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br><a href="#" onclick="wsp.internalLogin()">I am employee of XXX</a>          
  </form>
</div>
```

My function:

```
 internalLogin: function() {
$.ajax({
  url: '/xxx/public/internalLogin.do',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {
    location.reload(true);
  },
  error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    wsp.alertMessage(request.responseText);
  }
});
```

Comment: What does your login form/action look like?

Comment: @Brian Demers added

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to handle all of the login logic before you get into your action.

Shiro works out of the box with Servlet filters.  For example this example (which is just a couple JSP) doesn't actually handle any of the login logic:
https://github.com/apache/shiro/tree/master/samples/servlet-plugin

Other than rendering a login form. The Shiro Servlet Filter intercepts the post to the login page (in this case `/login.jsp`) and handles everything else automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't really understand how to use shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp when I have only div, not a page. I want to use Shiro as is, but I want to pass username to Shiro in Action beacause I don't want to rework my app.

Comment: What is the URL of your page that renders the login div?

Comment: I have the whole function. Please look at my first message.

Comment: If I use only link, app won't work. I don't really want to change my app for Shiro.

Comment: I'm not trying to be dense, but you should be able to use `/xxx/public/internalLogin.do` as your login page.  Your action could likely just `return SUCCESS`, (and return `SecurityUtils.getSubject()` for the remote user).  Or you could build your own bean based on that subject.  If you want to call the actual `.login()` yourself take a look at: https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html#the-currently-executing-subject